# Trying to boot up mysql and getting a permissions error

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, installation

I installed mySQL, I booted it up.

Now I'm trying to set the password in mysqladmin with this :

```
mysqladmin -u root -hec2-50-17-36-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com password 'my_password'
```

This returns :

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'ec2-50-17-36-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-127-34-29.ec2.internal' (using password: NO)'
```

But if I do this.. :

```
mysql -u root -hec2-50-17-36-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I can log right into the server, and it doesn't even ask for a password!

What's happening? What should I do from here?

Comment: What is the output of `mysql -u root -ppassword -h ec2-50-17-36-82.compute-3.amazonaws.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never set the root password for MySQL server, the correct syntax is:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: When I do this it just displays a list of all the mysqladmin commands.

Comment: Please append the output to your original post.

Comment: I tried your command but that's for setting a localhost. Mine is for a foreign host `ec2-50-17-36-82.compute-3.amazonaws.com`, and when I type : `mysqladmin -u root -hec2-50-17-36-82.compute-3.amazonaws.com -p password ACTUALPASSWORD` it says, `error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-127-37-29.ec2.internal' (using password: NO)'`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set root password? If so, remove the `-p` option to set it. If not and you don't remember, just reset by starting MySQL with `skip-grant-tables` option.

Comment: Cool it looks like that got me to the next error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the -p switch on mysqladmin says you're trying to use a password, and that the password is password.  It gets a little confusing because it seems your current password is password.  Try this:

```
mysqladmin -u root -h your_mysql_server -p'password' password yournewpasswordhere
```

Comment: I replaced my actual password with the word "password" for this example. In your example, which should actually be the word, password?